# WINE - Problem trying to open .msi file

Tags: 16.04, wine, cd

I've been trying to install a windows program directly from the CD on my ubuntu 16.04. However, every time I try to use the msiexec from wine, I get this message:

```
thai@thai-Vostro-5470:/media/thai/Menschen A1-1$ wine msiexec /i setup.msi
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:msi:ITERATE_DuplicateFiles We should track these duplicate files as well
fixme:msi:ITERATE_DuplicateFiles We should track these duplicate files as well
```

Does someone knows how to solve this and run the msi file? Please make the answer as much detailed as possible. I'm a beginner.

Comment: What software are you trying to install?

Comment: It's a study guide for my german class. It's called Menschen CD

Comment: It probably won't work.

Comment: Often CDs or DVDs coming with textbooks only install some sort of Windows viewer software but the content (audio files, flash animations, epub files) would otherwise also be accessible by Open Source software. Hard to say what content is on your CD. Try to view the files with your file browser Nautilus. You may also get an answer from the support desk of the publisher: http://support.hueber.de/